# How to make image background of textview semi transparent but not the text?

Tags: android, textview, transparency, opacity

I need to set an image background of a textview dynamically and make it semi transparent, with text with full opacity.

Something like this does, but compatible with <21 API.

```
android:backgroundTint="#80FFFFFF"
android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
```

When I use

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(x.getPicture());
textview.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
```

it works but later when I use the same resource to an imageview it remains transparent even though I use

```
imageView.setImageAlpha(255);
```

or

```
imageView.setAlpha((float) 1.0);
```

And this affects whole textview including the text itself.

```
textView.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
```

I tried everything I could find but didn't find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Whole layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg1">

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_toolbar_details"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_graphics"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_toolbar_details">

    <!--This is the imageview-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_toolbar_details" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_toolbar_details"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <!--This is the textview-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_toolbar_details" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llImg"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_last_viewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_previous"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llImg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.773"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/b_to_all"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vv_video"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.97" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_to_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_grid"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vv_video"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="176dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_to_favourites"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favourite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llImg"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.164"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/b_to_all"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_small_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_last_viewed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to first setAlpha on the picture and then set it to background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just realign your layout

```
//this is your root
<RelativeLayout>
     //this is your background
     //add your semi transparent for below imageView
     <ImageView android:height="match_parent" android:witdh="match_parent"/>

     //this is your text
     <TextView/ >

</RelativeLayout>
```

then programmatically

```
imageView.setImageAlpha(255); //it will not affect the textview
```

or just add `android:alpha` in xml at imageView

Comment: this is a good idea, I actually have the imageview under the textview, but I'm changing their visibility when switching over them, because my layout is quite complex and I cannot make it not to mess up the whole layout when trying to display both the imageview and the textview at the same time. do you think you can have a look at my code and try to tell me how to do it in my case? I'll paste the code in my original post.

Comment: I tried to nest the relative layout as you suggested but it makes the textview and the video view height 0dp although everything is set to match_parent. The first linear layout size is calculated dynamically according to screen size, that's why it's set to 0x0dp. It works, but when the relative layout is added it's not working anymore.

Comment: ok that 0dp height is apparently caused by the visibility set to gone, it looks ok in blueprint when set to in/visible, but it still doesn't appear in app when certain action done to change visibility (click or swipe). I ran out of ideas how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#80FFFFFF");
Drawable backgroundColor = new ColorDrawable(myColor);
backgroundColor.setAlpha(yourAlpha);

textView.setBackground(backgroundColor);
```

Comment: thanks, but I need an image in the background and set it to semi transparent or overlay it with semi transparent color, this only makes a transparent color.